# Will removing the mysql driver and replacing it with mysqlnd break plesk?

Tags: php, mysql, centos, plesk, mysqlnd

I have the current set up.

php 5.4.22,
Plesk 11.0.9,
CentOS 6.4 and
MySQL 5. something

I need to install php-mysqlnd but to do so I have to remove the php-mysql driver. My question is, is it possible to do this without breaking Plesk? Will Plesk work with the native driver?

Answer (score 0):

After much pain and trying everything I can think of including building various different versions of php 5.3.X and 5.4.X compiled with the mysql native driver nothing would work. Sadly I will have to go the route of cPanel instead of Plesk.